# Network graph with all possible paths for three contexts in a data frame and superimposing

Tags: r, igraph, sna

I want to make a network graph with all possible ways a letter/postcard can go from initial to final destination (there are three letters in the datasets, see figure below)[image]. Here is the dummy data.

```
postcard<- c('loveletter#234', 'loveletter#234', 'loveletter#234', 'officialletter#22','officialletter#22','officialletter#22','officialletter#22', 'newyearletter#24','newyearletter#24','newyearletter#24')
person<- c('Jane', 'Katie', 'Vince', 'John','Jane', 'Katie','Oliver','Katie','Becca','John')
df<- data.frame(postcard,person)
```

I want to create a network graph that shows the person as 'nodes' and the paths through which the post reaches the person as edges. For example, the graph should overlay the all the paths that occured in this transaction for 1) loveletter#234 2) officalletter#22 3)newyearletter#22 and superimpose. Can anyone suggest any ideas how to proceed this? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the `CJ()` from data.table package:

```
library(data.table); library(igraph);

g <- graph.data.frame(setDT(df)[, CJ(person, person), postcard][, .(V1, V2)][V1 != V2])
plot(g)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much sir!

Answer (score 1):

You can create an adjacency matrix first and load that into an igraph object.

```
t(table(df)) %*% table(df)
post <- t(table(df)) %*% table(df)

g<-graph.adjacency(post, diag=FALSE)

plot(g)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much sir!